# How do I call this method that registers device

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I do not know how to replace "method" with the following app delegate method.

viewcontroller

```
[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] method];
```

appdelegate

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {
    TUPushHelper * helper = [[TUPushHelper alloc] initWithTokenData:devToken];
    [helper registerDevice];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to call it programmatically. The delegate receives this message after the registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: method of UIApplication is invoked and there is no error in the registration process. **didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:** will be called otherwise.

To register your device for remote push notifications you have to do this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
...
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
...
}
```

**Edit:**
Check Apple Guide for APNS [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9)

also check out this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12)

Comment: Does the app have to be launched in order for it register device? I am trying to setup a switch statement that unregister devices and register devices instantly.

Comment: This will be done once on your app first launch. User will be prompted   about Push Notifications and he will allow \ deny them. 

Also you can't unregister remote notifications programmatically, because it makes no sense to do so. Registering doesn't mean you actually get notifications.